# Remote Debugging with XDebug from inside a Docker Container does not work

Tags: php, intellij-idea, docker, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to setup a dockered AMP environment and can't get the remote debugger working. My setup is as follows:

I have a database container running mysql which is working like a charm. I built a Docker image 'phpmysqli' with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM php:apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring

# zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN echo 'zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini; \
    echo xdebug.remote_enable=1 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini; \
    echo xdebug.remote_autostart=0 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini; \
    echo xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini; \
    echo xdebug.remote_port=9000 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini; \
    echo xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/php5-xdebug.log >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;

RUN echo 'date.timezone = Europe/Berlin' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/date.ini
```

I call

```
docker run --rm -ti  --name web -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 -v /path/to/projects:/var/www/html --link db:db  phpmysqli
```

After this phpinfo respectively php -i shows that xdebug 2.3.2 is up and running.

Next I setup a Server inside IntelliJ IDEA called 'Docker' with Host `127.0.0.1`, Port `8080` and Debugger Xdebug. I setup the path mapping analogous to the Volume mapping in the docker run statement.

In the *PHP->Debug settings* I checked that I use port `9000` for incoming connections, that I will accept external connections and that I will not ignore connections from unregistered servers.

After this I created a new PHP Remote Debug Configuration called Docker, too. Server is Docker, session id is `XDEBUG_IDEA`.

I can call PHP files on the Container, I can connect to the db via the link... but for some reason nothing whatsoever happens when I try to start a debug session. I tried using a cookie (and yes, I set `XDEBUG_IDEA` as session id in xdebug helper). I tried sending `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=XDEBUG_IDEA` as `GET`...

Can you smart people out there tell me what I missed?

Comment: No idea what is wrong, but you should connect in your container with a `docker exec -it web_id bash` and debug inside, as you would on any Linux server with such an issue

Comment: are you on Windows? If yes what are you using for your Docker host? (vagrant, other?)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: a workaround to try out: start your container with `docker run --net=host` (and remove `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:80`). This will make your container and your Docker host share the same network interface. As such from the container point-of-view, `localhost` will be the Docker host. xdebug might have less trouble figuring out how to connect to the debugger

Comment: This is not compatible with --link

Comment: if you start your db container also with `--net=host` you won't need link as your app would connect to `localhost:<port of your db>`

Comment: Works. Dammit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok - I have no idea why this is suddenly working. But now I can run the xdebug in conjunction with -p and --link. Is simply works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79422/discussion-between-thomasleveil-and-christoph-grimmer-dietrich).

Comment: im looking to do a similar setup.  what resolved it @thomasleveil

Comment: helped me: http://blog.flavia-it.de/xdebug-im-docker-container/

Comment: An earnest warning: XDebug messed up the program execution pretty badly. static properties of abstract classes were suddenly gone while being accessible just two lines above. It took me hours to realize that the code would run just fine with XDebug turned of :-(

Answer (score 16):

You can try with this configuration. php-apache build provide two method to compile and enable module php.
It's nicer to use `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` to set correct file configuration.

```
FROM php:5.4-apache

# Enable and configure xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_autostart=true' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_mode=req' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 ' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_port=9000' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_enable=1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

Comment: I've tried "pecl install xdebug" and it returns an error:

pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 5.5.0), installed version is 5.4.45
No valid packages found
install failed

Comment: I have the same error. I changed "FROM php:5.4-apache" to "FROM php:7.0-apache" and it resolved my issue :)

Comment: Please read the documentation about `xdebug.remote_connect_back` it tells: If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variables to find out which IP address to use. Apparntly with it enabled the remote_host ip setting is ignored.

Answer (score 7):

For me on a PHP, NGINX Docker environment using sublime, I got it to work with these settings:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

The one that took me forever to figure out was to set the remote_host to host.docker.internal.

Comment: host.docker.internal will only work for Docker for Windows or Docker for Mac and not available for Docker running in linux environments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-docker-for-mac-host-internal

Comment: @bender this is no longer the case: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007#issuecomment-578729356

Comment: Should you be attempting to configure xdebug under WSL2, note that host.docker.internal does not point to the subsystem and requires a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104199/issues-when-debugging-php-in-vscode-using-docker-and-wsl2

Answer (score 1):

close: `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0`
add: `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.102[your docker host/machine IP]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want do change xdebug config in the container and want to make it work using `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` you can set the HTTP-Header `X-Forwarded-For` to the IP of `host.docker.internal` und thus defines PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` which xdebug prefers and uses as the client IP instead of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Answer (score 0):

Within Docker 20.10+, Xdebug works both for Ubuntu and MacOS users with this counterintuitive configuration:

```
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
```

Tested with PhpStorm. Used to build a PHP7+ debian-based container with networking features and Xdebug capabilities, whatever the OS you run (maybe Windows as well but did not try yet).