# XDebug: Windows + Docker + PHPStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, boot2docker

My OS is Windows 10. I've run Docker via the boot2docker image. IDE I use is PHPStorm. What I want to do is debug with XDebug, but I don't get it running. I searched the Web and tried the examples I found but nothing helps. Is there anyone with the same architecture who can help me?

Edit: Nginx ist running on the server.

Current setup: 
**xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PhpStorm
```

**PhpStorm server**
Host is same IP I connect for SSH. Path mappings is enabled. Debugger is Xdebug
*I tried already with a specific DBPg Proxy but no success*

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594804/remote-debugging-with-xdebug-from-inside-a-docker-container-does-not-work ? See also https://hub.docker.com/r/tommylau/xdebug/ and http://rockhopper.dk/linux/docker-and-php-xdebug/

Comment: Also: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5534075#5534075 for initiating run/debug CLI scripts inside docker container from IDE

Comment: All of those sites I have already tried. No success. I googled a lot before I asked.

Comment: can you elaborate on your `I don't get it running.` ?

Comment: I would like to do that, but I don't know what to say. It is just not working. XDebug is installed, xdebug.ini is set, PHPStorm is configured and breakpoints are set. But it happens just nothing. I tried different setups. I post my current on my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it. I just forgot to forward the port. I've to run the container via `docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 9000:9000 -v /mnt/www/foo:/var/www/foo foo`.

Answer (score 1):

php.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
; Set to host.docker.internal on Mac and Windows, otherwise, set to host real ip
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/php/xdebug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following setting in ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```