# PHPStorm debug application deployed using docker inside vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a web app inside a VM (Ubuntu 14.LTS), created and provisioned using Vagrant, and **inside** that VM I'm running Docker with several containers (nginx, PHP, MariaDB...).

Now I'm trying to setup xdebug to debug my app with PHPStorm, but with no luck. I'm getting an error related to file mapping, and breakpoints doesn't work.

Comment: Docket inside Vagrant-controlled VM? Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32668258/783119