# What is the Linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

On Mac and Windows, it is possible to use `host.docker.internal` (Docker 18.03+) inside a container.

Is there one for Linux that will work out of the box without passing environment variables or extracting it using various CLI commands?

Comment: In 18.03 there is a docker.host.internal, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: There is open [PR](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/2348) which add "host.docker.internal" feature to Linux. Wait until it will be accepted, and now as a workaround, you can use [special container](https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host) which add unified "dockerhost" host and you can use this from docker.

Comment: It should be noted that docker-for-windows is a specific product line and will not cover docker on windows in general. For example I use docker on windows, using docker-toolbox (OG) so that it has less conflicts with the rest of my setup and I don't need HyperV. There is an answer in this thread using grep, awk and netstat, which works for me; although generally, mixed network environments can also be solved with LAN or WAN level hostnames, than machine hostnames. This is then more explicit and flexible / composable than hacking at docker VM's

Answer (score 248, accepted):

For Linux systems, you can – starting from major version `20.04` of the Docker engine – now also communicate with the host via `host.docker.internal`. This won't work *automatically*, but you need to provide the following run flag:

```
--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

See the answer here: [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/61424570#61424570)

See also this answer below to add to a docker-compose file - [What is the Linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal/67158212#67158212)

Comment: Is there a way to enable this in daemon.json or something? I'm thinking about test environments of Rancher and Kubernetes, where I don't want to take care of every single one of the many containers.

Comment: When running`--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` on CentOS I received the error `invalid argument "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" for "--add-host" flag: invalid IP address in add-host: "host-gateway"` Are you expecting to need to replace `host-gateway` with the actual host IP?

Comment: The magical IP number worked: `--add-host=host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1 \`

Comment: this works for me too. 172.17.0.1 is bridge network's gateway address in my case. if anyone has different network settings , they can get this by doing docker inspect.

Comment: Only newer docker versions have the magical string `host-gateway`, that converts to the docker default bridge network ip (or host's virtual IP when using docker desktop). You can test running: `docker run --rm --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu:18.04 cat /etc/hosts`, then see if it works and show the ip in the hosts file (there should be a line like `172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal` in it).

Comment: This is the correct answer for me!

Comment: Make sure that `live-restore: false` otherwise `host.docker.internal` doesn't seem to work under Linux.

Comment: Why doesn't Docker just do this automatically? I mean, really...

Comment: This answer fixed my issues on AWS codebuild.

Answer (score 318):

It depends what you're trying to do. If you're running with `--net=host`, [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) should work fine. If you're using default networking, use the static IP address *172.17.0.1*. I suspect neither will behave quite the same as those domains.

Comment: Wow! `172.17.0.1` actually works! I found this nowhere in the documentation or any of the forums complaining about `host.docker.internal` not working. Is this IP guaranteed to always link to the host machine?

Comment: You can edit your /etc/hosts and add 
    172.17.0.1 docker.host.internal

Comment: I can attest the `172.17.0.1`-trick this works with GitHub Actions!

Comment: I disagree that it "depends what you're trying to do". It does not depend what we are trying to do. We are trying to do only one thing that is connect to the host machine from inside the container. I already know it is discouraged and that's why we can't. But I have a task to solve. PHP-code needs to connect from inside Docker to my code editor.

Comment: @JulesColle It is "guaranteed" as long as you are on the default network. `172.17.0.1` is no magic trick, but simply the gateway of the network `bridge`, which happens to be the host. All containers will be connected to `bridge` unless specified otherwise. [See here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/)

Comment: This DOES NOT work on all cases. If you have other networks, a new interface is going to be created: 172.17.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.19.0.1 and so on (try `ifconfig` to list all interfaces). You have to manually obtain the IP for your network.

Comment: Is this possible while building?

Comment: You should run `ifconfig` on the host machine and view the `docker0` interface's `inet` field.

Answer (score 210):

If you are using [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) and Linux, you have to add it manually (at least for now). Use `extra_hosts` on your `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Do not forget to update Docker since this only works with **Docker v20.10+**.

Source: *[Support host.docker.internal DNS name to host #264](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-784985736)*

Comment: awesome! finally I can use xdebug on linux too :-)

Comment: if i want to access port 3000 on host, is this how i access it from container: `http://host.docker.internal:3000/` ?

Comment: Doing this the added host entry seems to be in the wrong subnet

Comment: I tried and does not work for me with docker version ` Version:          20.10.17`

Comment: This doesn't work for linux. It seems to "think" for a long time, then times out.

Comment: Same for me - doesn't work on Linux with Docker version 20.10.17, gets no response.

Comment: Exactly doesn't work for linux. I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: There is nothing about `host-gateway` in the whole Docker docs.

Comment: you can't resolve host-gateway in a container but yes this works on linux:
docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway centos:7  ping host.docker.internal

Comment: Make sure that `live-restore: false` otherwise `host.docker.internal` doesn't seem to work under Linux.

Comment: When ping works and curl times out, it is worth adding a firewall allow rule from 172.17.0.1/16

Comment: @jawira actually the source was above of your link https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-759737542

Answer (score 33):

One solution is to use a special container which redirects traffic to the host. You can find such a container on *[docker-host](https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host)*. The idea is to grab the default route from within the container and install that as a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) gateway for incoming connections.

An imaginary example usage:

```yaml
docker-host:
  image: qoomon/docker-host
  cap_add: [ 'NET_ADMIN', 'NET_RAW' ]
  restart: on-failure
  environment:
    - PORTS=999

some-service:
  image: ...
  environment:
    SERVER_URL: "http://docker-host:999"
  command: ...
  depends_on:
    - docker-host
```

Answer (score 22):

This is my solution:

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(ip addr show | grep "\binet\b.*\bdocker0\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1)
```

then in docker-compose:

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  docker.host: ${IP_ADDRESS}
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu VM, this is 172.17.0.1, which matches the above answer.

Comment: On Linux/Debian docker with this cmd I get nothing. Better is: `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`

Comment: The above `ip route` example prints the gateway, not the `docker0` io. The below should work:

`# ip route | awk '/docker0/ {print $9}'`

Comment: I use this solution combined with host.docker.internal flag in my case (Linux). Looks like host.docker.internal work fine in macOS

Answer (score 17):

For Linux, there isn't a default DNS name for the host machine. This can be verified by running the command:

```
docker run -it alpine cat /etc/hosts
```

This feature has been requested. However, it wasn't implemented. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1143). As discussed you can use the following command to find the IP address of the host from the container.

```
netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Alternatively, you can provide the host IP address to the run command via `docker run --add-host dockerHost:<ip-address> ...`.

Comment: That's not equivalent by any means. Having something that will resolve with dns gives you the ability to put it in config files without evaluating or sed'ing, or other funky stuff.

Comment: More often than not `grep | awk` can be just awk: `awk '/^0\.0\.0\.0/{print $2}'` :)

Comment: Well I would like to say thank you. This worked on my windows setup which uses docker-machine (I know OG). Normally I run a pass-through nginx so that I can talk to docker via a single container, but talking back to the host seems to be very OS / setup specific. It worked for me and I'm ecstatic for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

**tldr; Access the host via the static IP address `172.17.0.1`**

Doing HTTP request towards the host:

1. Run the following command to get the static IP address: `ip addr show | grep "\binet\b.*\bdocker0\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1`
2. Add the new IP address to allowed hosts
3. Use the IP address just found in your requests: `req = requests.get('http://172.17.0.1:8000/api/YOUR_ENDPOINT')`

Comment: Doesn't this depend on which `network` your container is running within?

Comment: Is it always `172.17.0.1`? Is it a special one? "17" looks odd.

Answer (score 15):

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264

```sh
IP=$(ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Host ip is $IP"
echo "$IP   host.docker.internal" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

It will add `host.docker.internal` to your hosts. Then you can use it in xdebug config.

Here is example of env variable in `docker-compose.yml`

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_autostart=On remote_enable=On idekey=XDEBUG remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log remote_port=9999
```

Answer (score 11):

Using the docker0 interface IP address, say 172.17.0.1, could be a good workaround.

Just be sure that the service you need to reach listens to external connections. A typical example is [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) who binds to 127.0.0.1 by default, resulting unreachable until you allow external connections (especially binding to 0.0.0.0).

Answer (score 11):

*host.docker.internal* exists only in Windows [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), because Docker Desktop for Windows runs the Docker daemon inside the special WSL VM Docker-Desktop.

It has its own [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and its own WSL2 interface to communicate with Windows. This VM doesn’t have any static IP address. The IP address is generated every time when VM is created and passed via *host.docker.internal* in the generated *[hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))* to every distribution. Although there isn’t any bridge or real v-switch, all ports opened on *eth0* of the VM internal network are mapped on the host Local network, ***but not on the `eth0` of the host***.

There isn't any real bridge and port mapping - nothing to configure.

Inside the WSL VM, its Localhost is the same as the localhost of the Linux machine. Two processes inside WSL VM can communicate via localhost. Cross-distribution [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) must use *host.docker.internal*. It is possible to create bridge inside WSL VM -Docker does it.

Comment: actually, host.docker.internal works on OSX if using docker desktop as well

Comment: Another hint [from the docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/): This (using `host.docker.internal`) is for development purpose and does not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, I was able to use the service name I was trying to connect to, e.g., one of my containers (*php-fpm*) was trying to connect to [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), so I used `mysql` as the host name, since that's the service name in my *docker-compose*.

Comment: This question is about connecting to the host system, not another service inside the same docker-compose environment.

Comment: Two things: a) it is the correct answer to the underlying problem (as opposed to hacking around DNS resolution using /etc/hosts) and b) using internals of docker to do the simple thing such accessing exposed ports is, and has always been, discouraged. That's what the -p or "expose" in docker-compose does.

I understand the question is a bit different, but it stems from another mistake which by mocking around with /etc/hosts is just covered - not fixed.