# Python send mail inside docker container with local SMTP server

Tags: python-3.x, docker, email, smtp, sendmail

I want to send mail with `smtp` lib on python. I understand that it uses local smtp service on port number 25. I have below codes. These codes run on my local without any problem and mail sends successfully. But when I  move them to docker container, mail is not sent and it doesn't give any error.

My codes:

```
from_mail = 'noreply@testmail.com'
to_mail = 'to@testmail.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
subject = 'Test Subject'
content = 'content test'

message = f"""\
      Subject: {subject}
      To: {to_mail}
      From: {from_mail}
      {content}"""
result = s.sendmail(from_mail, to_mail, message)
s.quit()
```

After running these codes, I get empty dict ({}) as `result` value. In the sendmail method description has this:

> ... the message was accepted for delivery to three
> of the four addresses, and one was rejected, with the error code
> 550.  If all addresses are accepted, then the method will return an
> empty dictionary.

Is it about network configuration? Should I configure any network settings?

Comment: What image is tour container based on? And how do you run the container? This may help solve your issue

Comment: My container based on `python:3.6-slim-buster`

Comment: can you share the dockerfile, please?

Comment: what is your operating system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you shared is SMTP client application. Assuming SMTP client standard library `smtplib` is used and SMTP server is running on localhost, the code will work in Docker container in the following conditions:

- You start the container with `--net=host`, then no changes is needed. calling `smtplib.SMTP('localhost')` will connect to SMTP server running on the host.
- You don't start the container with `--net=host`. Then you need to connect to `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` if you use Windows or MacOS. If you use Linux, may need to use another [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal). Essentially, the code is still connecting to SMTP server running on the host.
- You package SMTP server and the python stmp client application (code you shared) in the same Docker image. It's bad practice and should be avoided. But you can follow the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) to achieve it.

Please, do share the following to better understand the question:

More specifically:

- OS you are use. Docker for desktop behaves differently for Mac and Windows, [especially](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20docker0%20bridge,actually%20within%20the%20virtual%20machine.) in terms of networking features.
- `Dockerfile` you use. Otherwise it's impossible to run the image and replicate the issue you are facing and understand what you mean by `sendmail service is running in my container.`
- Fully working python code (including imports, etc...) Otherwise, it's not clear what `smtplib` you use.
- Links to documentation. If you use standard library `smtplib`, then its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) doesn't  have such description:

> sendmail method description has this:
>
> ... the message was accepted for delivery to three of the four addresses, and one was rejected, with the error code 550. If all
> addresses are accepted, then the method will return an empty
> dictionary.

Comment: `--net=host` didn't work for me (perhaps because I was using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`) but `host.docker.internal` worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the docker containers run in a separate network stack, so `localhost` does not mean the same thing inside a docker container as it does when your code runs directly on your computer.

Depending on how your SMTP server is set up, it might also be configured to refuse sending any email but those coming directly from your computer, and a docker container might be treated as an outsider that should not be sending an email through it.

I guess the simplest solution would be to run your docker container with `--net=host`. With this the network stack of the docker container will be the same as the stack of your computer and everything should work as if the code was running directly outside docker.

Comment: I have not any problems about connect to smtp service on docker container. When I change the connection informations - for example another port number or host name - I get connection error.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on host machine, try using the host IP instead of `localhost`.

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(HOST_IP)
```

Or as Arthur suggested, you can run the container in host network with `--net=host` and then continue using `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, sendmail service is running in my container. I want to send mail from container not using host.

Comment: Are you sure about that? You need to add more details to your question then. The dockerfile of your container, how you installed smtp service in the container etc