# Getting a list of services from inside a Docker container in Swarm Mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to find a list of all running Docker Swarm Mode services that have a specific tag - but from inside a container.

I know about the hack to mount docker.sock into the container, but I'm looking for a more elegant/secure way to retrieve this information.

Essentially, I want my app to "auto-discover" other available services. Since the docker swarm manager node already has this information, this would eliminate the need for a dedicated service registry like Consul.

Comment: I don't see why you consider mounting docker socket a hack. The idea of containers is to isolate applications, if you want to break this isolation I don't see other way to communicate with docker's daemon, the security is also up to the developer as it is often the case with docker.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a read-only docker REST API or something similar, to ensure that nothing can go wrong even if a client manages to break into the container. But well, mounting the socket read-only should be good enough, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query docker REST API from within the container.

For example, on MacOS, run on the host [to list docker images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#list-all-images):

`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.40/images/json`

To run the same inside the container, first install `socat` on the host.

Then establish a relay between host's  `unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock` and host's port 2375 using  `socat`:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock`

Then query host's 2375 port from within a container:

`curl http://host.docker.internal:2375/v1.40/images/json`

You should see the same result.

Notes:

- I don't have initialized docker swarm, so examples use docker images
  listing. Refer to Docker docs for listing services api.
- You can find out API version from the output of `docker info`
- Refer to [What is linux equivalent of “host.docker.internal”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal) if you don't use MacOS. Latest Linux docker versions should support `host.docker.internal`.