# Connecting to external MySQL DB in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have made a REST API using Golang and it connects to MySQL DB present on MySQL Workbench installed locally, now I wish to dockerise this API but how do I connect to external DB in Docker-Compose?
I'm new to docker, so have little idea of things.

```
func dbConnection() (db *sql.DB) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/testDB")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change **localhost** with the **docker.host** as I explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001152/418599 .

In other words you should write a docker build script which set an environment variable by:

```sh
IP_ADDRESS=$(ip addr show | grep "\binet\b.*\bdocker0\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1)
```

Then use **docker-compse** to build the image passing the above ip address as follow:

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  docker.host: ${IP_ADDRESS}
```

And finally address inside your GO sources the `IP_ADDRESS` environment variable in place of `localhost`.