# Access host from within a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized app and I use the following docker-compose.yml to run it:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        env_file:
            - ./docker/db/.env
        volumes:
            - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
            - ./docker/db/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        command: mysqld --sql_mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

    php:
        build: ./docker/php/7.4/
        volumes:
            - ./docker/php/app.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-app.ini:ro
            - ./docker/logs/app:/var/www/app/var/log:cached
            - .:/var/www/app:cached
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        links:
            - db
        env_file:
            - ./docker/php/.env

    webserver:
        image: nginx:1
        depends_on:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./docker/webserver/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - ./docker/logs/webserver/:/var/log/nginx:cached
            - .:/var/www/app:ro
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

I have a server that is not dockerized runing on my machine, I can access it via `localhost:3000`. I would like my `php` service to be able to access it.

I found people suggesting to add to following to my `php` service configuration:

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

But when I add this, then `docker-compose up -d` and try `docker exec -ti php_1 curl http://localhost:3000`, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 0 ms: Connection refused`. I have the same error when I try to `curl http://host.docker.internal:3000`.

I desperatly tried to add a port mapping to the `php` container:

```
ports:
    - 3000:3000
```

But then when I start the services I have the following error:

```
ERROR: for php_1  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint php_1 (9dacd567ee97b9a46699969f9704899b04ed0b61b32ff55c67c27cb6867b7cef): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint php_1 (9dacd567ee97b9a46699969f9704899b04ed0b61b32ff55c67c27cb6867b7cef): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: address already in use
```

Which is obvious since my server is running on that `3000` port.

I also tried to add

```
network_mode: host
```

But it fails because I already have a `links`. I get the following error:

```
Cannot create container for service php: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links.
```

I am running docker v20.10.6 on Ubuntu 21.10.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you are using version of docker that supports host.docker.internal.
If you are using linux version, then 20.10+ supports it.
For other systems you should probably consult documentation and probably some issues on github of docker-for-linux / other projects OS revelant.

After that...

Make sure extra_hosts is direct child of php service:

```
php:
    extra_hosts:
        host.docker.internal: host-gateway
    build: ./docker/php/7.4/
```

Try using `ping host.docker.internal` first to check whether your host machine responds correctly.

Make sure that your service on port 3000 is working properly and there is no firewall issue.

Remember that `localhost` means always local ip from current container point of view. It means that `localhost` inside container maps to local container IP and not your host machine IP. This is a reason for sending extra_hosts section.

Also docker.host.internal is not your host loopback interface.
If service you are trying to reach listens only on localhost interface then there is no chance to reach it without doing some magic with iptables / firewall.

You can check what service is listening on which interface / ip address running following command on your host machine: `netstat -tulpn`

This should return something like following output:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39195           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

From docker container I can reach services listening on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) but cannot access 631 port as it is only on 127.0.0.1

```
$ docker run --rm -it --add-host="host.docker.internal:host-gateway" busybox
/ # ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
^C
--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.060/0.092/0.124 ms
/ # telnet host.docker.internal 631
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.1): Connection refused
/ # telnet host.docker.internal 22
Connected to host.docker.internal
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
```

Comment: I forgot to add these details but I am using docker v20.10.6 on Ubuntu 21.10. It should be compatible with host.docker.internal. When I run `ping host.docker.internal` the host machine responds correctly. I made sure extra_hosts is a direct child of php service, but with no success. The service on port 3000 is running correctly as I can reach it in my browser.

Comment: I've made some edit to explain it further.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and the above didn't make `127.0.0.1:3000` available. I can't hit it with a `curl` or `ping`.

Comment: Same. In my case it doesn't make 50001 and 8332 available. I see now why. netstat will show the services are only listening on 127.0.0.1 (which is localhost), this need to be set to 0.0.0.0 for docker to be able to connect to.

Comment: What's then the correct way to expose a service locally and make it accessible from containers but not on internet? AFAIK if your machine is "open", listening on 0.0.0.0 make it accessible remotely.

Comment: Took a while to find this answer. Thanks for including `localhost` vs `0.0.0.0`, that solved my issue.

Comment: @DevilaN that ```--add-host="host.docker.internal:host-gateway"``` helped, it was not working on CentOS, but was working without it on WSL

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `extra_hosts` into the compose file as @DevilaN said,

```yaml
php:
  extra_hosts:
    host.docker.internal: host-gateway
```

There is another job you should check is that the firewall allows port `3000` in the host as this service will use the host network to bypass things from docker.

The successful port `465` test like:

```bash
root@192b86bff47a:/# nmap -p 465 host.docker.internal
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-31 06:42 UTC
Nmap scan report for host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1)
Host is up (0.00016s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
465/tcp open  smtps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

If you do not allow the port `3000` in the host, the result will be like,

```bash
root@192b86bff47a:/# nmap -p 465 host.docker.internal
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-31 06:45 UTC
Nmap scan report for host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
465/tcp filtered smtps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.34 seconds
```

Note **filtered** state means firewall obstacle.