# Unable to connect to host IMAP server from inside Docker container

Tags: linux, networking, docker-compose, imap

I have an IMAP server running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I am able to connect successfully to this server using `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8000 -crlf` .

I am trying to access this server from inside a docker (version 24.0.0) container running on the same machine. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) post to set up the networking and included

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

in my docker-compose.yml for the relevant container. I am able to ping the host using `curl host.docker.internal:80`, correctly displaying the nginx page of the host. However, trying to access the IMAP server using `openssl s_client -connect host.docker.internal:8000 -crlf` results in the following error:

```
481BA4E8D57F0000:error:8000006F:system library:BIO_connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:114:calling connect()
481BA4E8D57F0000:error:10000067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:116:
connect:errno=111
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006997/access-host-from-within-a-docker-container) post I have tried to debug the issue. I use UFW as a firewall but have disabled it whilst debugging. `netstat -tulpn` on the host machine shows `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 38233/bridge` which I believe means the IMAP server is listening on all interfaces.

I have searched extensively and have been unable to find a solution to this.