# How to correctly config docker-compose to connect to localhost (non-docker service)

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm new to Docker. I'm build a Spring Boot Application deploying on Docker.

Here is my example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  user:
    container_name: user
    image: user-service
    build:
      context: user-api/
    ports:
      - "3001:8000"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - /home/ubuntu/logs/user_service:/opt/app/logs
    networks:
      - api_network

  cms:
    container_name: cms
    image:cms-service
    build:
      context: cms-service/
    ports:
      - "3003:8000"
    restart: always  
    volumes: 
      - /home/ubuntu/logs/cms_service:/opt/app/logs
    networks:
      - api_network

networks:
  api_network:
    driver: bridge
```

In the server machine, there's a Redis Server running on Ubuntu. I cannot connect the the Redis Server from Docker container to the host machine.

Here is my redis config inside **application.properties**

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=Password123!@#
```

I also tried to change the localhost to

- 127.0.0.1
- 172.17.0.1
- 0.0.0.0
- host
- host.docker.internal

That's I've found on the internet. But nothing works. Do I need to specifically config anything to allow my Spring Boot Service inside Docker connect to Redis that's running on localhost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal

Comment: @РоманСергеевич 
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
Is not working for me.

Comment: Try to add     
extra_hosts:
      - "localhost:127.0.0.1"
inside docker-compose is still not working.

Comment: A Redis server is pretty lightweight; can you add a Redis container to your `docker-compose.yml`, instead of trying to reach out of Docker space?  `localhost` in Docker generally means "this container" (and so in this question there are three different context-specific meanings of `localhost`).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion. I will talk to the Infra team about this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is *probably* due to the fact your Redis is bound to the address 127.0.0.1 (which is the default configuration) and your containers are not running on the `network` host.

To solve this, you should reconfigure Redis to bind to both `127.0.0.1` as well as to the IP address of the host as seen from *api_network* (`sudo ip addr show` on the host): the easiest thing to do here, if your scenario allows that, is to just bind Redis to `0.0.0.0` (via redis.conf).

As an alternative, you may also want to run your containers on the `host` network instead of using the *api_network* bridge: this appears to be overkill according to your issue, by the way, and may lead to security issues and exposed network ports.