# Docker Container Can not access Docker host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

In the docker compose file i added api server as a service and mongodb is installed in my local pc. But when the api run in docker container it could not connect with 127.0.0.1:27017.

Here is the docker-compose file.

```
networks:
  test_network:
    name: test_network
    driver: bridge
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3031:3031"
    networks:
      - test_network
```

Why this problem is happening
and how i can resolve this problem ?

Comment: To connect outside a docker container instead of `localhost or 127.0.0.1` try this `host.docker.internal`

Comment: For more info on troubleshooting checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the IP address **127.0.0.1:27107** refers to the container itself.

You have to address the above port, but the **host ip** as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001152/418599).