# How to curl to host from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm trying to setup an api gateway using docker container on my machine.

The api container is map to port `8000` and run on a `bridge network` but the api is running directly on my machine without a container on port `19108` .

What I'm trying to archive is when a HTTP request hit the endpoint `/order` on the port `8000` it will make another HTTP request to the port `19108` and return the response which was received but can't seem to find a way to make it work since i don't know the host machine ip.

I've tried using `host.docker.internal`, the `ping` command returns response but the `curl` just return `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid`.

Are there any workarounds or i should just use the `host` network instead?

Comment: Could you try with my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001152/418599 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do that, you can set the container in network mode host.

```sh
docker run --network host myapp
```

Note, that you cant map the ports now anymore, and the container app will be accessible as if it were running on the host system itself.