# host.docker.internal not working on prismagraphql/prisma:1.34 on docker-compose (1.29.2) docker 20.10.9 CentOS 8.4.2105

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, prisma, centos8

I want deploy a 'prismagraphql/prisma:1.34' container using :

- docker-compose version (1.29.2)
- docker 20.10.9
- CentOS 8.4.2105

but when i use 'host.docker.internal' on host not working.
So i try to use :

```yaml
extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

My project three files :

datamodel.prisma :

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
}
```

prisma.yml :

```yaml
endpoint: http://localhost:4477
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
```

docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
    - "4477:4477"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4477
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: host.docker.internal
            database: postgres
            schema: public
            user: postgres
            password: yrt
            rawAccess: true
            port: '5432'
            migrations: true
```

I try many incidents to disable firewall add to /etc/hosts ... => NOT WORKING

Here i create a GitHub repo :  https://github.com/performautodev/local-prisma-1.34-using-docker-compose-1.29.2-docker-20.10.9-on-CentOS-8.4.2105

Comment: What's the actual error you get?  What URL are you trying to connect to?  Are you running any particular GraphQL query that triggers this, or do you not get this far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

✔️ Solved :

The answer is to use the output of this command :

```sh
ip route | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}'
```

OR

```sh
[root@localhost dev]# ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:e6ff:fe93:a426  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:e6:93:a4:26  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 90 (90.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and use the line :

```sh
inet 172.17.0.1
```

so the yml file look like this :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4477:4477"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4477
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: 172.17.0.1
            database: postgres
            schema: public
            user: postgres
            password: 'YOUR_PASS'
            rawAccess: true
            port: '5432'
            migrations: true
```

IMPORTANT:
my /etc/hosts is as default :

```sh
[root@localhost dev]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

issue refs :

[host.docker.internal not working on prismagraphql/prisma:1.34 on docker-compose (1.29.2) docker 20.10.9 CentOS 8.4.2105](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494586/host-docker-internal-not-working-on-prismagraphql-prisma1-34-on-docker-compose)

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8771

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42919

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9677

Answer (score 0):

`host.docker.internal` is not supported on Linux. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal) StackOverflow answer on the workaround.

Comment: Hello,
I know i try to use "extra_hosts host.docker.internal:host-gateway" but not working, can u clone my project on github and test please ?

Comment: If you think this question is the same as another, please flag it as a duplicate rather than putting the question link in an answer.

Comment: Try the other solutions and write the IP address directly instead of using `host.docker.internal`. The output of: `ip route | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}'`. Also check if your database is accessible on your host's `localhost`.

Comment: I believe you missed the second answer on the linked post that indicates `host.docker.internal` is now supported on Linux.