# Connection Airflow Docker to PostgreSql Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow

I am using Airflow and PostgreSQL in Docker.

So I set up a PostgreSQL database on port 5433. Container (384eaa7b6efb). This is where I have my data which I want to fetch with my dag in Airflow.

> docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS
       PORTS                              NAMES
384eaa7b6efb   postgres               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago    Up 4 hours
       0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp             test-instance
421d443540fb   apache/airflow:2.0.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   18 hours ago   Up 4 hours (healthy)     
       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             airflow_docker-airflow-webserver-1
ff4bea4f16dd   apache/airflow:2.0.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   18 hours ago   Up 4 hours
       8080/tcp                           airflow_docker-airflow-scheduler-1
4cead3ee6667   postgres:13            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 hours ago   Up 4 hours (healthy)     
       5432/tcp                           airflow_docker-postgres-1
8bb2cefd456e   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 days ago     Up 5 hours (healthy)     
       0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   airflow_docker-flower-1
5c4b96d9c5a0   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 days ago     Up 5 hours (healthy)     
       8080/tcp                           airflow_docker-airflow-worker-1
3442eae78844   apache/airflow:2.2.0   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 days ago     Restarting (1) 11 seconds ago                                      airflow_docker-airflow-triggerer-1
7e945051435f   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago     Up 5 hours (healthy)     
       6379/tcp                           airflow_docker-redis-1
```

I created a new server connection on PgAdmin to access my database:

[image]

I can see my data and everything is fine.

So now I created this dag to query the data from that database:

```
def queryPostgresql():
        conn_string="dbname='postgres' host='localhost' port='5433' user='postgres' password='admin'"
        conn=db.connect(conn_string)
        df=pd.read_sql("select name,city from public.users",conn)
        df.to_csv('postgresqldata.csv')
        print("-------Data Saved------")
```

when i run the dag in airflow,

```
[2021-10-17 14:37:16,485] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

What I am doing wrong here? Is it the way i should add a connection?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Change the host to; `host.docker.internal`.

### Long Answer

This depends on the Os you are using. In order to access the host's network from within a container you will need to use the host's IP address in the docker. Conveniently, on Windows and Max this is resolved using the domain `host.docker.internal` from within the container. As specified in [docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host):

> #### I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac.

There is also a workaround for this in linux which has been answered in
[What is linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal)

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same configurations. If all your containers are within the same network, you can access your database by `<postgres-container-name>:<port>` (in your case `test-instance:5433`)