# How to consume static file hosted on Tomcat 9 Server in Docker Image

Tags: docker, tomcat

Version of Tomcat Server: tomcat-9.0.10

Basically I have a docx file hosted in the ROOT folder of my tomcat server. If i try to get the file on my browser it works using "http://localhost:1212/Manufacturing.docx". When I try to use the file in a local build of my webapp it works. But when i try to use "http://localhost:1212/Manufacturing.docx" in my app hosted on the docker container, it fails to get the file (it seems like it cannot establish a connection). Any idea why I can server the file outside of the container but cannot inside the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access `localhost` from a container, it resolves to the localhost within the container and not the host.

Possible solutions:

1. If you are using Docker 18.03+ and are on Windows / Mac, accessing `host.docker.internal` will resolve to the 127.0.0.1 of the host machine.
2. Run your container using `docker run -d --network=host your-image:tag`. This way your container will share the networking namespace with your host and `localhost` inside the container will be the same as `localhost` on the host.

Also see: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) and [What is linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, my bad.. thanks for your help!