# Docker on Linux connect to localhost through host.docker.internal with specific port

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue reaching my local machine from a docker container. It is created with Laravel sail like this:

```yaml
laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
```

And this is the network config:

```yaml
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
```

When I login to the container: `docker-compose exec laravel.test sh`

And run: `curl host.docker.internal` I get a response.

But like this: `curl host.docker.internal:8000` I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8000: Connection refused`.

How do I have port forwarding while connecting to my local maching?

I seen I should use "host" as the driver for the network, but that doesn't work at all.

Result of `docker ps`

```sh
9e6716ad920e   sail-8.1/app                  "start-container"        3 hours ago   Up 3 hours             8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                                        integrationproxy_laravel.test_1
a2e8e4b31536   selenium/standalone-chrome    "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours             4444/tcp, 5900/tcp                                                                     integrationproxy_selenium_1
874d8b620bb4   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                             integrationproxy_mysql_1
5bdcd577ac54   redis:alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp                                              integrationproxy_redis_1
878eb11c9a13   getmeili/meilisearch:latest   "tini -- /bin/sh -c …"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:7700->7700/tcp, :::7700->7700/tcp                                              integrationproxy_meilisearch_1
a94a0ccf3741   mailhog/mailhog:latest        "MailHog"                3 hours ago   Up 3 hours             0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, :::1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp, :::8025->8025/tcp   integrationproxy_mailhog_1
```

Comment: i suppose APP_PORT =8080? your docker container has the 8080 port open, not your local  machine... aka, that port that you are specifying is for incoming request, not outgoing requests... Connection refused is due to the fact that  your "local pc" has the port 8080 closed

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001152/418599 ...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Like this?  `ports: - '8080:80'` . That doesn't work.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca This is not talking about ports specifically.

Comment: So to be clear, the connection refused problem only arises when I try to access a specific port. In this case 8000.

Comment: Can you paste the result of `docker ps` ?

Comment: Sure, added it to the main post @Philippe

Comment: From `8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp`, we can see `8080` is forwarded to `80`. But where is `8000` forwarded to ?

Comment: Hmm, I feel noobish here. So looking at my docker-compose file, which is some laravel default setup. Where is 8080 even defined? And how would I forward 8000? It's not obvious to me at all.

Comment: This isn't working: '8000:8000'. While starting the containers it says port 8000 is already in use. (The application I have running locally and want access to from the container is running on that port)

Comment: Run `netstat -anp | grep 8000` as root to see what process is listening on it.

Comment: This one :). As I expect: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38508/php