# Docker - access to host network and docker network

Tags: docker, centos

I have a docker container and I want to give it `--network=host` AND `--network=postgres`.
I need to connect to the host network in order to use the host datadog server (UDP) and the `postgres` network for its database.

Trying to add both network results in `docker: conflicting options: cannot attach both user-defined and non-user-defined network-modes.`.

Any idea what's the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Can you take a look at these questions to see if they provide a solution to your specific case? 1. [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) and 2. [What is linux equivalent of `host.docker.internal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal)

Comment: Also, note that `host.docker.internal` won't work, if your Datadog service binds to `127.0.0.1:[port]` and not to `0.0.0.0:[port]`

Comment: Thanks - worked! regards the first URL, it was too massive, I couldn't figure out what to do, still. the answer in this post + yoru comment helped me.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yeah, its huge because it has all the "historical context" of how people were trying to solve it at the beginning only for `Linux`, then for `Docker for Windows / Mac` and finally with `host.docker.internal` when it became available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the the IP address of the host machine from within you container in order to send requests to the host machine.

A better solution, however, would be to use `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` or

```yaml
extra_hosts:
    - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

where `host.docker.internal` is then the host name of the host network inside your docker container. This name can of course be changed to your liking.

Credit: https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66

Comment: This is covered in the canonical question [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).