# Trouble connecting docker containers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently learning docker and how I can dockerize my REST API but I'm having problems connecting my api image with api written in Spring and my Postgres database image from Docker Hub. I have watched multiple examples but I just cannot figure what I'm doing wrong.
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  restapi:
    container_name: stats-api
    image: 'statistics-api'
    build: .
    networks:
      - api-postgres
    ports:
      - "7000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./target/statistics-api.jar:/statistics-api.jar
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - api-postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin123#
      POSTGRES_DB: statistics
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data/postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U admin"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  postgres-data:
networks:
  api-postgres:
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD target/statistics-api.jar statistics-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "statistics-api.jar"]
```

This is my application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  datasource:
    password: admin123#
    username: admin
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5332/statistics
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show_sql: true
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet
```

This is the error I get after running `docker-compose up`:

[image]

Also one note I'm using Docker on Windows that uses WSL version 2.

Comment: what is the problem? Can you provide an error trace or similar?

Comment: @usuario Hello, I just updated post I added the error trace. The Postgre image starts up normally, this is the log from api.

Comment: You used the wrong port. With "5332:5432" you opend 5332 on host. Just use 5432 in application.yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every docker container is it's own machine, therefore, the IP is different. In your case, rather than using `localhost`, you have to specify the `hostname` of the `postgres` container and use that hostname in your `application.yml` instead.

When using `localhost` in your container, you're not referring to the **host** but rather the **container** itself, and most commonly, you won't have the database running in the **same container** as your consumer.

What you're doing is trying to break out of the container and then connecting to another container that is already in the network of the first one. That's a bad practice and unnecessary.
If you do want to actually use the host (which should pretty much only be if you access something that isn't in a container), follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67158212/21038281)

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me but now I get error which says that connection to the postgres is refused.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to use the port **in the container**, not the **published** port, so in your case, that would be `5432`. Additionally, make sure that the hostname matches and you set it manually on the `postgres` service.